# Align TextBlocks in a ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, uwp

I have a ListView with few TextBlocks in it. I would like to align those textblocks to get columns, but the problem is that content can have different length. 
Is there any way to set the length of each text block, and if the value is shorter, to add spaces?

```
<ListView x:Name="InfoBird_ListView" IsItemClickEnabled="False" IsHitTestVisible="False">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate  x:DataType="local:SelectedBirdData">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding dataId}"    Margin = "0,0,0,0" FontSize="16" />
            <TextBlock Text=":"                   Margin = "0" FontSize="16" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding latitude}"  Margin = "10,0,0,0" FontSize="16" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding longitude}" Margin = "10,0,0,0" FontSize="16" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding altitude}"  Margin = "10,0,0,0" FontSize="16" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding timeStamp}" Margin = "10,0,0,0" FontSize="16" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image: My ListView]

Comment: Try setting the width for the textblock

Comment: @KenTucker brilliant answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this,

1. Set a constant `Width` for all the `Textbox's` such that they all fit the data.
2. Use a `Grid` and `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` to create a tabular structure such that you can fit the data into columns. Below is the updated `DataTemplate:

   ```
   <Grid Margin="5,40">
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="21*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="76*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="87*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="1224*"/>
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding dataId}" Margin = "0,0,0,0" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="0"/>
       <TextBlock Text=":" Margin = "0" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="1"/>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding latitude}" Margin = "10,0,0,0" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="2"/>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding longitude}" Margin = "10,0,0,0" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="3"/>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding altitude}" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="4"/>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding timeStamp}" Margin = "10,0,0,0" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="5"/>
   </Grid>
   ```

The 2nd approach is more adaptive to dynamic Window Sizes